# Stack fails to download any ghc

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am renting a Ubuntu server. I want to execute a build on it, but Stack is failing to download the GHC. I could not found any solution on the internet. I also tried to downgrade Stack, but that fails when trying to download GHC. Can you help me? Do you have a solution or workaround for that?

```
stack install
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Preparing to download ghc-8.10.3 ...
Download expectation failure: HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "downloads.haskell.org"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = [("User-Agent","The Haskell Stack")]
  path                 = "/~ghc/8.10.3/ghc-8.10.3-x86_64-deb9-linux.tar.xz"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 ConnectionTimeout
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is an issue with the firewall settings on the rented Ubuntu server.  The industry standard is to have these very tight by default when first created.  It is very likely that Stack does not have permission to create the connection it needs to download GHC.  To get a more detailed answer, it would help to know more about the Ubuntu server you are renting.  You also might see if you can connect to `https://downloads.haskell.org` with something like [`wget`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) or [`curl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl).

Comment: curl works. So it will be something with the firewall correct? So I have to figure out, how to configure that for Stack correct?